# Reconciling two notions of finite descent obstructions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $k$ be a number field and $X$ a smooth geometrically connected variety over $k$. We denote by $H(k,X)$ the set of sections $G_k \rightarrow \pi_1(X)$, where $G_k$ is the absolute Galois group of $k$ and $\pi_1(X)$ is the algebraic fundamental group of $X$. Denote also by $\sigma_{X/k}:X(k) \rightarrow H(k,X)$ the map associating to a $k$-rational point the class of its corresponding section. For a place $v$ of $k$, we have a restriction map $\alpha_v:G_{k_v} \rightarrow G_k$ and a map $\beta_v:\pi_1(X_v) \rightarrow \pi_1(X)$, where $X_v$ is the base change of $X$ to $k_v$.

The *finite descent obstruction* set is the set $X^f$ consisting of points $(P_v)_v \in \prod_v X(k_v)$ for which there exists a section $s \in H(k,X)$ satisfying $$s \circ \alpha_v = \beta_v \circ \sigma_{X_v/k_v}(P_v)$$ for all places $v$. When $X$ is proper, this set is closed.

Although the notation $X^f$ is used, there was no indication of what $f$ is. In the classical theory of obstruction of rational points, $f$ refers to a torsor $Y \rightarrow X$ under some group $G$ (originally the $k$-groups of multiplicative type or tori). So $X^f$, usually written as $X(\mathbb{A}_k)^f$ (we will write it like this to distinguish it from the other one), is the set $$X(\mathbb{A}_k)^f = \bigcup _ {\sigma \in H^1(k,G)}f_\sigma(Y_\sigma(\mathbb{A}_k)).$$

In particular, if $G$ is a finite group $k$-scheme then $X(\mathbb{A}_k)^f$ is called the finite descent obstruction by $f$.

They don't look similar but how are they related? Say, can we compare $X^f$ with $X(\mathbb{A}_k)^{Br_1}$? I know for certain that if $G$ is a $k$-group of multiplicative type then $X(\mathbb{A}_k)^{Br_1} \subset X(\mathbb{A}_k)^f$.

Comment: The "$f$" in $X^f$ is an abbreviation for "finite", doesn't refer to any specific map in the first set you consider. This is equal to the intersection of what you call $X(\mathbb{A}_k)^f$ when now $f$ runs through all the torsors under all finite group schemes $G$.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch I really appreciate your clarification, for the entire first half of the question I took the notations straight out of your paper. Thank you.